# Moving NSPopover as NSRulerView scrolls

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, scroll, nspopover

### Background

The default implementation of `NSPopover` will move the popover when the view it's shown over scrolls (and has special handling for when the `NSRect` it's attached to scrolls out of view). An `NSPopover` can be shown over an `NSRulerView`, but the `NSPopover` doesn't move when the document view is scrolled (apparently because `NSRulerView` doesn't handle scrolling as other views do, using a drawing offset instead of a moving viewport).

### The Question

How can the default move behavior be recreated for an `NSPopover` that's attached to an `NSRulerView`?

### Sample code

- ViewController:

  ```
  @interface ViewController : NSViewController
  @property (weak) IBOutlet NSScrollView *scrollView;
  @property (strong) LineNumberView *ruler;
  @end

  @implementation ViewController

  - (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      self.ruler = [[LineNumberView alloc] initWithScrollView:self.scrollView orientation:NSVerticalRuler];
      self.scrollView.verticalRulerView = self.ruler;
      self.scrollView.hasVerticalRuler = YES;
      self.scrollView.rulersVisible = YES;
  }
  //...
  @end
  ```
- LineNumberView:

  ```
  @implementation LineNumberView
  -(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
      [self popOver:[self convertPoint:event.locationInWindow fromView:nil]];
  }

  -(void)popOver:(NSPoint)point {
      NSRect anchor = [self rectForPoint:point];
      PopoverController *pop = [[PopoverController alloc] init];
      [pop showOver:anchor ofView:self];
  }

  -(NSRect)rectForPoint:(NSPoint)point {
      NSTextView* textView = (NSTextView*)self.scrollView.documentView;

      NSUInteger rectCount;
      NSRectArray frameRects = [textView.layoutManager
          rectArrayForCharacterRange: NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0)
          withinSelectedCharacterRange: kNullRange
          inTextContainer: textView.textContainer
          rectCount: &rectCount
      ];

      const CGFloat kWidth = NSWidth(self.bounds);
      const CGFloat kHeight = NSHeight(frameRects[0]);
      const CGFloat x = 0;
      CGFloat y = point.y - fmod(point.y, kHeight);
      //y += NSMinY(self.scrollView.contentView.bounds);

      return NSMakeRect(x, y, kWidth, kHeight);
  }

  @end
  ```
- PopoverController:

  ```
  @interface PopoverController : NSViewController<NSPopoverDelegate>
  @property (strong) NSPopover *popover;
  @end

  @implementation PopoverController
  -(instancetype)init {
      if ((self = [super init])) {        
          NSTextField *label = [NSTextField labelWithString:@"Pop!"];
          [label setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(kPadding, kPadding)];
          self.view = [[NSView alloc]
              initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(
                  0, 0,
                  2 * kPadding + label.frame.size.width,
                  2 * kPadding + label.frame.size.height)];
          [self.view addSubview:label];

          self.popover = [[NSPopover alloc] init];
          self.popover.contentViewController = self;
          self.popover.behavior = NSPopoverBehaviorTransient;
      }
      return self;
  }

  -(void)showOver:(NSRect)anchor ofView:(NSView*)view {
      [self.popover showRelativeToRect:anchor ofView:view preferredEdge:NSMaxYEdge];
  }
  ```
- Within the main storyboard, the `ViewController's scene has an`NSScrollView`as a descendent view, connected to the`ViewController`'s`scrollView` outlet.